# What's wrong with my approach to this improper integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int _0^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+5}\right)-\left(\frac{6}{3x+2}\right)$$
$$\int _0^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+5}\right)-2\int _0^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{3}{3x+2}\right)$$
$$\lim _{b\to \infty }\left[\ln\left(x^2+5\right)\right]^{b}_{0} = \ln(\infty ) - \ln(5) $$
$$2\cdot \left(\lim _{b\to \infty }\left[\ln\left(3b+2\right)\right]^{b}_{0}-\ln\left(2\right)\right) = \ln(∞)−\ln(4)$$

So, $$\ln(\infty ) - \ln(5) - (\ln(∞)−\ln(4)) = \ln(\frac{4}{5})$$

Comment: You cannot compute the difference of two integrals that diverge to $\infty$. You cannot take the logarithm of $\infty$.

Comment: Be careful $\infty - \infty$ is not $0$, is undefined. You have to solve the limit

Comment: Also you cannot subtract $\ln \infty$ with itself as if it were a number

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. But when I put the equation into Symbolab, I get $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\ln \left|x^2+5\right|-2\ln \left|3x+2\right|\right)=-\ln \left(9\right)$. What's going on? Doesn't each expression inside the brackets go to infinity?

Comment: But thats not the proper way to solve the limit, try writting both $ln$ in only one

Comment: @GabN.: Yes, but their difference does not go to infinity.

Comment: Yes, but that does not tell you anything about the difference! Look for instance at $x^2-x$, $x-x^2$ and $(x+1)-x$ when $x$ grows to $\infty$.

Comment: I still don't completely understand -  so the difference of the two 'ln's in the last equation is $-ln(9))$, but how do I work that out, and what is the significance is the difference of two 'ln's (or is that just because subtraction was the operation?) I'm fairly new to maths, so I'm not amazing!

Comment: You're taking the limit too soon.  To see what's going on, continue to work with the proper integral from $0$ to $b$.  Evaluate both halves of your difference, use the properties of the natural logarithm to evaluate your answer at $b$, and *then* take limits.

Comment: Don't forget *dx* on your integrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** to solve this correctly, notice that 
$$\ln(x^2+5) - 2\ln|3x+2| = \ln \frac{x^2+5}{(3x+2)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks -  but could you perhaps provide a next step too? From my (limited) understanding I perceive this to be $ln(\frac{∞}{∞})$

Comment: @GabN. Your fraction is $\frac{1+\frac{5}{x^{2}}}{9+\frac{12}{x}+\frac{4}{x^{2}}}$.

Comment: Ah! I see! So subbing in b (as b tends to infinity) gets me 1/9, so the ln evaluates to -ln(9), then applying x = 0 and subtracting gets me ln(4/45). Thank you very much!